# Animation hover and keyframes to resize my video do not work and gives me a separate keyframe?

Tags: html, video, resize, keyframe

I need to know why my video is not resizing when I set in the keyframes and why it gave me a separate keyframe colored box. In my answer, I had already put the video in the div tags, but now how can I resize the video through keyframes? Could anybody help me now?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<title>Home</title>  
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
<style>
div {width: 100px;      
     height: 100px;      
     background-color: rgb(109, 53, 149);      
     position: relative;      
     animation-name: resize;      
     animation-iteration-count: infinite;      
     animation-play-state: paused;           
     animation-duration: 3s;         
     animation-direction: alternate;    
}        
 
div:hover {    
     animation-play-state: running;      
     animation-iteration-count: infinite;    
}    
  
@keyframes resize  {0%   {width: 260px; height: 260px; left:0px; top:0px;}      
                   25%  {width: 220px; height: 220px; left:100px; top:100px;}      
                   50%  {width: 180px; height: 180px; left:180px; top:180px;}      
                   75%  {width: 120px; height: 120px; left:270px; top:270px;}      
                   100% {width: 50px; height: 50px; left:350px; top:350px;}    
}
</style>  
</head>
<body>            
<div>     
  <video src="a1.mp4" controls autoplay width="300" height="300" loop muted playsinline>      
 Your browser does not support the video tag.    
</video>
</div>          
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your video isn't inside the div you attributed the @keyframe animation to,
copy the video element then paste it inside of your div and that should work